# Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to `Python` and am trying to install the [FuncDesigner](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/FuncDesigner) package. It gives the following error:

Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument and points to the following line:

```
kw = {'skipArrayCast':True} if isComplexArray else {}
r = ooPoint((v, x[S.oovar_indexes[i]:S.oovar_indexes[i+1]]) for i, v in enumerate(S._variables), **kw)
```

Any ideas what to change the line starting with **"r = "** to to get it to work?

I'm using a `Python 3` version.

Comment: If you want to know why parenthesis is required, have a look at [bpo-32012: Disallow trailing comma after genexpr without parenthesis. by serhiy-storchaka · Pull Request #4382 · python/cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/4382).

Answer (score 20):

... Put the genex in parens, just like the error tells you to.

```
r = ooPoint(((v, x[S.oovar_indexes[i]:S.oovar_indexes[i+1]]) for i, v in enumerate(S._variables)), **kw)
```

Comment: Any reason why this is required?

Comment: if you ever get to figure out why this is required, please drop an answer. Thanks

Comment: It seems to be required when there is more than one function argument. The Python 2 exception text is better: "SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument"

Comment: @Cooper having run into this issue myself and solving it by simply parenthesizing the genex like Ignacio suggested, my guess would be any argument utilizing list comprehension requires the function to “get” its value first. And the way you make that happen, is by “ordering” the arguments within a function call by parenthesizing the relevant argument (just like order of operations in math).

Comment: My guess is that there are some cases where the parsing can be ambiguous without the parentheses, so they force an error all the time rather than sometimes parse it differently than the coder expected

Comment: please explain and not just post code only answers

Answer (score 0):

In my case python 3.11 solve the problem