# Python pulp constraint

Tags: python, pandas, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I am trying to add a constraint to linear programming problem in python using `pulp` library. I tried code below.

```
for week in range(14,52), i in I.index:
    k = week
    model += sum(x[(i, j, week, B)] for week in range(k, k+13), 
                                        j in J.index) <= 1
```

where I and J have following indexes

```
I.index = ['A','B','C']
J.index = [1,2,3]
```

The error I get is `SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument`. I have researched this link 
[Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137503/generator-expression-must-be-parenthesized-if-not-sole-argument)
however it didn't seem to resolve my issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Idk pulp, but I think that even your first line is wrong, since it's compile to something like: `for week in (range(14,52), i in I.index)`, so your for loop is just iterate over 2 elements, the first one is the `range` generator(maybe this is the issue) and the second one is a bool statement(like 1 in [1,2,3]==True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or Duan's comment looks correct the syntax used should be

```
for week in range(14,52), i in I.index:
    k = week
    model += sum(x[(i, j, week, B)] for week in range(k, k+13)
                                    for j in J.index) <= 1
```

but in this case it will be much faster if you use the lpSum() function

```
for week in range(14,52), i in I.index:
    k = week
    model += lpSum(x[(i, j, week, B)] for week in range(k, k+13)
                                    for j in J.index) <= 1
```