# Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument: using join

Tags: python, django

I'm getting following exception while run the server:-

SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument to the following line:

```
return '\n'.join(' | '.join(value.rjust(width) for value, width in row, widths) for row in table
```

I'm using a Python 3 version. I also tried to upgrade the django but still it returns same exception.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137503/generator-expression-must-be-parenthesized-if-not-sole-argument)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `zip` your `row` and `widths`, and you're missing a closing parenthesis on the outer join:

```
return '\n'.join(' | '.join(value.rjust(width) for value, width in zip(row, widths)) for row in table)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i tried with this and its working fine. Thanks

Comment: yeah @Paul thank you.

Comment: @PriyuSonar there is a grey tick button that you can press to say that you accept the answer, and then I will get some points for being helpful :) See here for an example https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979/1115026

Comment: i accepted your answer, Thank you :) @Paul